# How to stop QThread with infinite loop

Tags: c++, qt

I have infinite thread for data reception:

```
void RxFTDI::process() {

    qDebug() << "RxFTDI hello!" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    while(true)
    {
        FT_GetStatus(ftHandle,&RxBytes,&TxBytes,&EventDWord);
//        FT_GetQueueStatus(ftHandle, &RxBytes);
        if ((ftStatus == FT_OK) && (RxBytes > 0))
        {
//            qDebug() << "rx " << RxBytes;
            FT_Read(ftHandle, &RxBuffer, RxBytes, &BytesReceived);

            if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
                // FT_Read OK
            }
            else {
                // FT_Read Failed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it looks that my app crashes when I want to remove that thread with `delete RxThread;`:

```
bool Ftdi::quitRxTxThreads ()
{
    emit Tx->finished();
    emit Rx->finished();

    delete Tx;
    delete Rx;

    RxThread->terminate();
    TxThread->terminate();

    delete TxThread;
    delete RxThread;

    return true;
}
```

Full project is on github: https://github.com/bLLAZ/ftQt
The idea is simple. GUI + two separate threads: Tx and Rx. It is my first Cpp application. If some of you could take a look at it and give some hint how to organize it better, I would really appreciate.

Comment: An improvement would be to eliminate the `while(true)`. Just create a break condition for it.. ;-)

Comment: Terminating thread in from outside is always dicouraged and should be considered last resort. It can break stack frames, objects destruction. I mean, anything can go wrong

Comment: Since you're using `QThread` you could consider using its [interruption mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested).

Answer (score 8):

Killing/terminating thread should not be done from outside of it as it may lead to corruption of data. Even Qt documentation says something about this:

> Warning: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The
>   thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be
>   terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to
>   clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use
>   this function only if absolutely necessary.

So what to do? I suppose You can use variable shared between threads to to finish them gracefully like this. Put some flag in the class like this:

```
public:
    atomic<bool> finish = false;
```

Then, change process a bit:

```
void RxFTDI::process() {

    qDebug() << "RxFTDI hello!" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    while(!finish.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
    {
        FT_GetStatus(ftHandle,&RxBytes,&TxBytes,&EventDWord);
//        FT_GetQueueStatus(ftHandle, &RxBytes);
        if ((ftStatus == FT_OK) && (RxBytes > 0))
        {
//            qDebug() << "rx " << RxBytes;
            FT_Read(ftHandle, &RxBuffer, RxBytes, &BytesReceived);

            if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
                // FT_Read OK
            }
            else {
                // FT_Read Failed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally function running the threads:

```
bool Ftdi::quitRxTxThreads ()
{
    emit Tx->finished();
    emit Rx->finished();

    delete Tx;
    delete Rx;

    RxThread->finished.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    TxThread->finished.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    //now wait for them to finish
    RxThread->wait();
    TxThread->wait();

    delete TxThread;
    delete RxThread;

    return true;
}
```

Of course it is not the cleanest design and so on and so forth, but hopefully You get the idea ;)

Answer (score 8):

From Qt 5.2 there are 2 new functions.

```
bool QThread::isInterruptionRequested() const
void QThread::requestInterruption();
```

In your thread you can have a function which runs forever and checks for `isInterruptonRequested`

```
void long_task() {
     forever {
        if ( QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested() ) {
            return;
        }
       // run your tasks
    }
}
```

When you want to finish you can use the thread object, i. e. from MainWindow to request a stop.

```
threadObject->requestInterruption();
```

The use of void `QThread::terminate()` needs to be studied very well and only in rare cases the function may be used.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution I have seen so far, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Or another way is use the send a stop signal from another thread, terminated is a risky way to stop a thread, I always use quit() then wait().